logic issue for needle gauge ui
i'm trying to make a gauge that begins flashing when the gauge value reaches a set threshold and increases the flashing speed linearly as the value approaches the gauge maximum value. currently the flashing speed functionality doesn't behave as intended and changes and only changes its flashing speed based on the rate of change for the gauge value and not the gauge value itself.
i've tried changing the logic every way i can think possible but nothing seems to give the desired result.
this is the current code :
import SwiftUI

struct NeedleGauge: View {
    var value: Double
    var minValue: Double
    var maxValue: Double
    var temperatureValue: Double // Temperature value to display inside the gauge

    @State private var isFlashing = false
    @State private var flashSpeed: Double = 1.0
    
    // Define min and max temperatures for flashing logic
    let minTemperature = 23.0
    let maxTemperature = 32.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 20.0)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(135))
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width)

                    Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat((value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)))
                        .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: gradientColors(value: value, minValue: minValue, maxValue: maxValue)), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(135))
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width)

                    Text("\(temperatureValue, specifier: "%.1f")°C")
                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width * 0.15))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Circle().fill(Color.white).frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.72, height: geometry.size.width * 0.72)) // Adjust the size of the background circle
                        .offset(y: 0)
                        .zIndex(1) // Ensure the text is above the gauge
                        .opacity(isFlashing ? 0.5 : 1.0) // Adjust opacity for flashing effect
                        .animation(isFlashing ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: flashSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : .default) // Flashing animation
                }
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .padding(20)
                .onAppear {
                    updateFlashingState()
                }
                .onChange(of: temperatureValue) { _ in
                    updateFlashingState()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to determine gradient colors based on value
    private func gradientColors(value: Double, minValue: Double, maxValue: Double) -> [Color] {
        let range = maxValue - minValue
        let normalizedValue = (value - minValue) / range

        // Define blue and red colors
        let blueColor = Color.blue
        let redColor = Color.red

        // Interpolate between blue and red based on normalized value
        let fraction = CGFloat(normalizedValue)
        let color = Color.mix(color1: blueColor, color2: redColor, fraction: fraction)

        return [color]
    }

    // Function to update flashing state based on temperatureValue
    private func updateFlashingState() {
        let threshold = 0.5 * (maxTemperature - minTemperature) + minTemperature // 80% of the temperature range
        
        // Determine if flashing should be active based on temperature value reaching the threshold
        isFlashing = temperatureValue >= threshold
        
        if isFlashing {
            let temperatureRange = maxTemperature - minTemperature
            let adjustedValue = (temperatureValue - minTemperature) / temperatureRange
            print("temperature value ", adjustedValue )
            
            // Calculate flashSpeed to increase as temperatureValue approaches maxTemperature
            flashSpeed = 0.1 * adjustedValue // Adjust base flash speed and scale it
            print("flashSpeed is ", flashSpeed)
        } else {
            flashSpeed = 1.0 // Reset to default speed if not flashing
        }
    }
}

struct NeedleGauge_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NeedleGauge(value: 50, minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, temperatureValue: 25)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

struct NeedleShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

extension Color {
    static func mix(color1: Color, color2: Color, fraction: CGFloat) -> Color {
        let r = Double(color1.components.red) * Double(1 - fraction) + Double(color2.components.red) * Double(fraction)
        let g = Double(color1.components.green) * Double(1 - fraction) + Double(color2.components.green) * Double(fraction)
        let b = Double(color1.components.blue) * Double(1 - fraction) + Double(color2.components.blue) * Double(fraction)
        return Color(red: r, green: g, blue: b)
    }

    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let uiColor = UIColor(self)
        var red: CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        uiColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        return (red, green, blue, alpha)
    }
}


As I understand it,  what you want to do is base the flash rate on the current temperature value's percentage of the way into the range minTemperature...maxTemperature, isn't that right?
If that's what you're looking, it's an elementary bit of arithmetic; you need to construct a mapping where you know what the rate of flashing should be if we are at minTemperature and what the rate of flashing should be if we are at maxTemperature, and then you map the actual temperature into the flashing range.
It will help to have on hand an extension that maps a number from one range into another:
extension FloatingPoint {
    func map(from range1: (Self, Self), to range2: (Self, Self)) -> Self {
        let clampedSelf = min(max(self, min(range1.0, range1.1)), max(range1.0, range1.1))
        let normalizedSelf = clampedSelf - range1.0
        return range2.0 + (range2.1 - range2.0) * normalizedSelf / (range1.1 - range1.0)
    }
}

So now, by way of illustration, let us say that minTemperature is 23 and maxTemperature is 32, and that we want to flash 2 times a second if the temperature is 23 and we want to flash 20 times a second if the temperature is 32. (It's only an example! You would put in the real numbers to suit your tastes.)
Then you want to get
temperatureValue.map(from: (minTemperature, maxTemperature), to: (2, 20))

If you try it, you will see that if temperatureValue is 24, we will flash 4 times a second, but if temperatureValue is 30, we will flash 16 times a second. As you can see, we are staying proportionately within the proposed range of 2 to 20, which seems to be the sort of calculation you are trying to perform.
